# PyQt & unittest - Testing signal and slots

Tags: python, pyqt, unit-testing

I have a pyqt application that I'm writing unit tests for, and it relies heavily on signals and slots. To properly test it, I have to check that the correct signals are sent.

What is the best way to do this? I see that the Qt library has a QSignalSpy, but I can't find any reference to this in PyQt. The only option I can think of is to mock emit, e.g.

```
import testedmodule

def myemit(signal):
    ....

testedmodule.QObject.emit = myemit
```

but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Edit:
My module is run as a thread, in that case overriding emit of an instance no longer worked after starting the thread so I updated the code above to reflect this.

Comment: Let Phil (the author of PyQt) know that it's needed.  He'll either add it or suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can try connecting a slot to your signal, prepare your test, then call qApp.processEvents() to let the signal propagate. But I don't think it's 100% reliable.

It's a pity that QSignalSpy is not part of PyQt indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more elaborate version of what I suggested myself, not necessarily the best solution for unittest, but I think it will be of interest to others that come across this:

Posted by Carlos Scheidegger on the pyqt mailing list (http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pyqt-pykde/9242/focus=9245)

```
_oldConnect = QtCore.QObject.connect
_oldDisconnect = QtCore.QObject.disconnect
_oldEmit = QtCore.QObject.emit

def _wrapConnect(callableObject):
    """Returns a wrapped call to the old version of QtCore.QObject.connect"""
    @staticmethod
    def call(*args):
        callableObject(*args)
        _oldConnect(*args)
    return call

def _wrapDisconnect(callableObject):
    """Returns a wrapped call to the old version of QtCore.QObject.disconnect"""
    @staticmethod
    def call(*args):
        callableObject(*args)
        _oldDisconnect(*args)
    return call

def enableSignalDebugging(**kwargs):
    """Call this to enable Qt Signal debugging. This will trap all
    connect, and disconnect calls."""

    f = lambda *args: None
    connectCall = kwargs.get('connectCall', f)
    disconnectCall = kwargs.get('disconnectCall', f)
    emitCall = kwargs.get('emitCall', f)

    def printIt(msg):
        def call(*args):
            print msg, args
        return call
    QtCore.QObject.connect = _wrapConnect(connectCall)
    QtCore.QObject.disconnect = _wrapDisconnect(disconnectCall)

    def new_emit(self, *args):
        emitCall(self, *args)
        _oldEmit(self, *args)

    QtCore.QObject.emit = new_emit
```

just call enableSignalDebugging(emitCall=foo) and spy your signals until
you're sick to your stomach :)

Answer (score 1):

Note QSignalSpy is [available](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qsignalspy.html) as `QtTest.QSignalSpy` in PyQt5.